# Trying to display the literal value of a concatenated cell in another cell

Tags: excel-formula

I'm having trouble phrasing my question, so here's a screenshot. Basically I want G2 to be a field I can copy and paste into a field on a website for billing purposes. The TEXTJOIN function is the closest I've gotten to making this work but it still isn't right. I'm having the following problems:

- The price of each fruit loses its ending 0's during concatenation
- I intend to keep adding more fruits, but =TEXTJOIN(E:E) includes E1 which is obviously the heading
- The resulting string in G2 isn't copy-and-paste-able without first copying and selecting Paste Value within Excel

Screenshot for reference: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFQx7.jpg]

I might not be able to avoid the last problem without VBA but I'd like to at least navigate around the first 2 issues. I suppose creating a button that would output G2's value to a Notepad document would work as well, or something along those lines.

Comment: If you are going to use VBA anyways why not make a UDF and make it perfect in one go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In E2 put:

```
=A2&"("&TEXT(D2,"$#,##0.00")&")"
```

to do the concatenation.

[image]

Then just specify the start in E2:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,E2:E1040000)
```

[image]

---

Also you can skip the helper columns with the following array version of TEXTJOIN:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,$A$2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("zzz",A:A))&"("&TEXT($D$2:INDEX(D:D,MATCH("zzz",A:A)),"$#,##0.00")&")")
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

When you copy a cell to the clipboard and paste it anywhere but Excel it should only paste the text, but that may depend on the website also.

Comment: Thanks so much for your explanation. It worked just as described.

That led me to one last step in this spreadsheet. I'm trying to conditionally join the text based on a label in another column, using an IF inside the TEXTJOIN as an array function, but when I do I'm getting a strange error. The values labeled A join properly, but the values labeled O cause this error. https://imgur.com/a/WfS9ivl

Comment: You have to use the same size array for column G as you do for Column E, `$G$2:$G$1040000`

Comment: Oh! There we go. Using =TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(G:G="A",E:E,"")) as an array formula does the trick.Thanks so much for your help. Would've been working at this all day! It's my first use of the site and thanks to you it's made a great impression already.